# How to group by columns with sparse data in R's ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am working with a data.frame (df) in R like

```
  A  B G1 G2 G3
1 1  6  0  1  0
2 2  7  0  1  1
3 3  8  1  1  0
4 4  9  0  0  1
5 5 10  1  1  1
```

Columns A and B are just continuous and numeric. G1, G2, and G3 are categories for each row, where a 0 indicates that row is not in that category and a 1 indicates that row is in that category. Obviously, a row may be in multiple categories.

I want to use ggplot2 (geom_point) to make scatter plots that are color coded by G1:G3 categories or grouped in some other way by G1:G3. I have no clue how to do this. I am currently plotting A vs B using the following code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = A, y = B)) + geom_point()
```

I currently have no clue how to incorporate my categories in G1:G3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways I will suggest, the first is the simple case where the only missing value in your code is to set the aesthetic color to one of your categories.  In this case you will create a ggplot for each category.

```
set.seed(1)
A <- rnorm (20)
B <- rnorm (20)
G <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, 60), 20, 3)

df <- cbind.data.frame(A, B, G)
colnames(df) <- c("A", "B", "G1", "G2", "G3")
head(df)
# A           B G1 G2 G3
# 1 -0.6264538  0.91897737  0  1  1
# 2  0.1836433  0.78213630  1  0  0
# 3 -0.8356286  0.07456498  0  0  0
# 4  1.5952808 -1.98935170  0  1  0
# 5  0.3295078  0.61982575  1  1  1
# 6 -0.8204684 -0.05612874  0  0  0

# Note colour = factor(G1) to get categorical, if colour = G1 get continuous
gg_point <- ggplot(df, aes(x = A, y = B, colour=factor(G1))) + geom_point()
gg_point

# Example on how to edit the legend values
G1_legend <- scale_colour_discrete("G1")
G2_legend <- scale_colour_manual("G1", values=c("blue", "red"), labels=c("non-member", "member"))

gg_point + G1_legend
gg_point + G2_legend

# you can use grid.arrange to plot all categories together once you create them
grid.arrange(gg_point_G1, gg_point_G2, gg_point_G3, ncol=3) # or nrow = 3
```

The second approach reshapes the data by combining categories into a variable, and uses facets to separate plots by category variable

```
library(reshape2)
df.melt <- melt(df, id.vars=c("A", "B"))
head(df.melt)
# A           B variable value
# 1 -0.6264538  0.91897737       G1     0
# 2  0.1836433  0.78213630       G1     1
# 3 -0.8356286  0.07456498       G1     0
# 4  1.5952808 -1.98935170       G1     0
# 5  0.3295078  0.61982575       G1     1
# 6 -0.8204684 -0.05612874       G1     0

gg_point2 <- ggplot(df.melt, aes(x = A, y = B, colour=factor(value))) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ variable)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the categories to factors in a data.table. Then set shape or color to a factor and your ggplot will illustrate the category:

```
library(data.table)

a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(6,7,8,9,10)
G1 <- c(0,0,1,0,1)
G2 <- c(1,1,1,0,1)
G3 <- c(0,1,0,1,1)

cc <- data.table(a,b,G1,G2,G3)
cc[,G1 := as.factor(G1)][,G2 := as.factor(G2)][,G3 := as.factor(G3)]

ggplot(cc)+
  geom_point(aes(a, b, color = G1, shape = G2), size = 4)
```

[image]

So, the color (red or blue) displays the value for the G1 category while the shape (diamond or triangle) displays the value of the G2 category. You can manipulate this many ways.

Comment: Yes, this is a nice alternate way to condense the plot if you have limited categories, you can also set the aesthetic size to G3: `ggplot(cc)+
  geom_point(aes(a, b, color = G1, shape = G2, size = G3))` to get all 3 in there...

Comment: @johncarter Yup.. and you can plot multiple plots with indulividual categories on a large grid with the gridExtra package. Many many options for visualization.